# How do you manage your extensions version control in Magento

Tags: php, svn, version-control, magento

I have been  trying to figure out the best way to start working on building Magento extensions for release. I would like to be able to have individual svn repos for each extension. It seems like there is some difficulty trying to figure out the best way to develop these in a way that makes things easy in terms of version control. Obviously you want to work on the extension, inside of a Magento application, but you wouldn't want to have worry about ignoring all the files except the ones that are for the extension.

I thought about using svn:externals but I don't think that is the answer since you need to have certain files mixed into other directories and its not really standalone. From what I read with externals it doesn't seem like this is a good choice.

So I am just looking to see what others do to setup their extension development environment, maybe just ignoring all other files is the way to go. We also thought about sym linking but that would mean writing a script that would do this for all developers and I am not sure that this would be that great either since people may setup their projects different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symlink script you are thinking of already exists. It's called [Module Manager](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) (modman) and it's great for managing multiple modules in one Magento install. Modman allows you to checkout and manage multiple SVN repos in the same folder.

However, please note that a security change in Magento 1.4.2.0 makes it impossible to symlink template files into app/design, so a workaround is needed. More info in [this bug report](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=10487).

Comment: Yeah, I think I read about that a while back when Ashley Schroder  first wrote a blog article about it.I guess need to look back at it.

Answer (score 2):

Ashley Schroder had introduced this kind of techniques in magento imagine conference. You can visit his website : [Engineering your magento store](http://www.aschroder.com/2011/02/magento-imagine-2011-presentation-notes-and-links-engineering-your-magento-store/)

Answer (score 0):

I use git for managing extension codebase, deployment and symlinking + override to the bug mentioned in each extension